# Will Naofumi be wary of the waves?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

Do you think, in the upcoming season of the Shield Hero, Naofumi will be wary of the waves? Since this is my understanding:

1. When they fight the waves they almost overpower monsters in the other world
   (or)
2. He might be brought to the said world to fight the waves in the coming season
   (or)
3. There might be an altercation that, when the heroes present themselves near the Dragon Clock Tower, it activates the waves.
   (or)
4. They might start an army near their homeland and it might trigger a rebellion when the Shield Hero finds (3rd point) is true.

What happens in the light novel regarding this?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to make the question more objective. We can't speculate, but we *can* answer based on what happens in the light novels that the anime is based on.

Comment: Thank you I was confused on the term but you cleared it out